# Difference in behavior between [file normalize $path] and realpath($path) when symbolic link is followed by `..`

Tags: c, linux, tcl

I have found a difference in behavior between Tcl's `[file normalize $path]`
and the path resolution used by the calls in C, such as `open()` and
`realpath()`.

It revolves around the use of symbolic links immediately followed by `..`.

The setup: given this directory structure (notice that `sidedir_link` is a link to a
different directory):

```
/tmp/fileA.txt
/tmp/sidedir/fileA.txt
/tmp/subdir/fileA.txt
/tmp/subdir/sidedir_link -> /tmp/sidedir
```

the current directory is `/tmp/subdir`, and I have created the command
`utils::realpath` to be a Tcl call to the C function `realpath()` in
`<stdlib.h>`.

Here's the transcript.  The first two calls show how both resolve a symbolic
link.  And the last two show the difference in behavior when dealing with
the `..` that immediately follows the symbolic link.

```
wish% file normalize sidedir_link/fileA.txt
/tmp/sidedir/fileA.txt
wish% ::utils::realpath sidedir_link/fileA.txt
/tmp/sidedir/fileA.txt
wish% file normalize sidedir_link/../fileA.txt
/tmp/subdir/fileA.txt
wish% ::utils::realpath sidedir_link/../fileA.txt
/tmp/fileA.txt
```

*Note:* The difference is `/tmp/subdir/fileA.txt` versus `/tmp/fileA.txt`.

Specifically, `[file normalize $path]` appears to lexically resolve the `..`
by removing the preceding portion of the path, whereas the C calls actually
resolve the symbolic link and **then** apply the `..`.  If the symbolic link
were to `/some/location/far/far/away`, the resolved path would be
`/some/location/far/far/fileA.txt`.

I couldn't find any mention of this in the Tcl docs, the wiki, or in the bug
tracking system.

So, is this a Tcl bug?  A C-library bug?  Expected behavior?

I'm using Tcl 8.4.9 and Redhat 6 (yes, a bit behind the times...)

*Note:* I can reproduce the same behavior in Tcl 8.6.1

The reason this is important is that the Tcl/Tk GUI is indicating that a file exists (because it uses the `file` commands), but when the backend actually opens the file using the C-library call `open()`, the run fails (because the path is different, and doesn't exist).

Comment: This looks like an interaction with Tcl's virtual filesystem support. In theory the path could point to a web server path and `realpath()` wouldn't work there, so the code has to work from the textual representation. In fact, the open dialog from Tk could even show you a file inside a database BLOB and your C-library `open()` call will fail as well. So this is maybe expected behaviour, but maybe a bug. There were various bugs found in that part of the code when handling corner cases, so not sure how this one would be classified.

Comment: @schlenk I guess you could contort it that way, only that `file normalize` actually does the right thing with symbolic links (using the concrete implementation of the Unix file system) when you do not use `..`.  So, it could similarly use the concrete implementation to resolve the `..`.

For example, I could have a database BLOB where `..` is a valid file name (and doesn't refer to the parent directory), in which case the Tcl implementation would appear to never work...

Comment: Not sure you know the Tcl vfs system, so the blob example might be bad. But to get back to the point, there are some tests about `file normalize` and `..` in the path (see tests `filesystem-1.*` in https://core.tcl.tk/tcl/artifact/0a3fce191778e80a). I didn't see your exact case in there, so maybe its a missed corner case.

Comment: I'll check those out.  It's a bit hard to parse w/out using the interpreter, but they do have a bunch with ..

Comment: It wouldn't be the first time there's been a bug in `file normalize`, but we can't just use `realpath()` as that doesn't know about Tcl's VFS layer. (I don't try to fix problems in this subsystem; it scares me.)

Comment: @DonalFellows FWIW, I did look more closely at the file tests shipped with Tcl 8.4, and they didn't test this situation.

Comment: @TreyJackson I wouldn't be at all surprised. I really don't want to maintain the VFS code though; it's really tricky in places and has all sorts of subtleties that are only important on some platforms (or with a third party VFS “mounted”). I save my attention for other parts of Tcl…

Comment: @DonalFellows understood.  I ended up overriding `[file]` and `[open]` to catch this condition and DTRT (at least as I see it).  Intentionally skipping the other possible commands like `[glob]` that also deal with file paths.  It's such a corner case...

Answer (score 1):

This smells a lot like a bug to me — given what I remember of the history of the pathname resolution and normalization code, I wouldn't be at all surprised — so I've made [Bug Ticket #6c49da8a19](http://core.tcl.tk/tcl/tktview?name=6c49da8a19). I don't maintain this part of Tcl so I don't know even how to begin to address it other than by filing a bug report. If you want to provide further information, please do so via our issue tracker.